# django rest framework - add ManyToMany relationship

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-rest-framework

I'm having trouble adding to `tag` field through many to many relationship on `article` object.

I'm able to *replace* all current `article.tags` by passing HTTP method of `PATCH`.

However, I would like to add to the existing relationships on `article.tags`, rather than replacing.

I cannot find a built in way to do this. Am I missing something obvious?

My `article` modedel serializer has the following field:

`tags = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True)`

Answer (score 0):

In your 'article' model serializer instead of
    tags = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True)
use the below code
    tags = TagSerializer()

here 'TagSerializer' is the model serializer of 'Tag' model like

```
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tag
```